# Does the surface area divided by bounding box feature have a name?

Tags: image-processing, image-morphology

I'm writing a connected component system and one of the descriptors I can easily compute is the surface area along with the component's rectangular bounding box.

What is surface area divided by bounding area called? (or any mixture of these two parameters).

For example, if my object were a rectangle, this parameter would be 1.0.

Comment: you cannot divide an area by a bounding box. mabye by the box's area or circumference... please be more specific. also which kind of bounding box are you talking about?

Comment: @Piglet Fixed, I meant the area the bounding box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Extent** or **rectangularity**, apparently:

> Extent of an image object is defined as area of the image object
> divided by the area of its bounding rectangle.

Source: Question text in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49026/what-is-the-application-difference-between-extent-and-solidity-in-image-processi

> Rectangularity is the ratio of the object to the area of the minimum
> bounding rectangle.

Source: Page 45 in http://www.cyto.purdue.edu/cdroms/micro2/content/education/wirth10.pdf

But the definitions I've run across do not always fully specify the rectangle. The ambiguity is related to the concept of "ferret box". Ferret boxes' edges do not have to be parallel to the image axes like good old bounding boxes. So depending on which you choose, your "extent" value might change.

Comment: There’s the concept of Feret diameters. Feret (the name of a person, with one R) defined the concept of length of the projection under a given angle. The longest Feret diameter is a meaningful value, as is the shortest Feret diameter. There is also the concept of the minimal bounding box, a box tight around the object, and rotated in such a way that its area is minimal. Usually its shortest side corresponds to the shortest Feret diameter (apparently there are cases where this does not hold, though I haven’t seen such a case). I have never heard of a “Feret box” nor a “ferret box”.

Comment: Here's course material from another university that mentions "Ferret box": https://www.ukaachen.de/fileadmin/files/institute/medizinische-informatik/Publications/ASMI/Ostwald_T_-_Objekt-Identifikation_anhand_regionenbeschreibender_Merkmale_in_hierarchisch_partitionierten_Bildern.pdf (Page 19)

But Wikipedia spells Feret with only one R, so I suppose that is the correct spelling. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: A course I am taking spells it as "ferret", with two R's. I cannot share our material because of university policies, but below is a paper that spells the word with two R's. Note that neither my university nor this paper's university nor the slides linked above are from an English speaking country. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Dimension-terms-F-min-Minimum-Ferrets-diameter-F-max-Maximum-Ferrets-diameter_fig1_318506747 (Dipova, Nihat. (2017). Determining the grain size distribution of granular soils using image analysis. Acta Geotechnica Slovenica. 14. 29-37.)